# Navigate to a specific item in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am using ViewPager with 4 pages. I need a code to navigate to the first page on specific events. Any idea how? The PagerAdapter has the methods  setPrimaryItem, but I am uncertain how to use it.
Another relevant question is how to trigger swiping the pager through code, I could use that to swipe all the way to the needed view, and I imagine it will also look better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1)`, this method will navigate to that page with the swipe animation.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot this method.